# How to simplify multiple if else statement using Java

Tags: regex, string, java-8, refactoring

I've use-case where I've to validate `two inputs` and return `success/failed` in responses.
Please find my code below, I feel I'm using too many if-else statements - how can we simplify this?

I've to check given string is null or not, then check if matches the pattern - then return success or failure based on below given conditions:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        // Scenario 1: -> Return Success
        String input1 = "bearer sDjdESddfEsdfdfwere2sEDaa2SmnsSkeew";
        String input2 = "bearer kiIkdqAplMNbeieW3dJKidAkdmElsEpsles";

        // Scenario 2: -> Return Success
        //String input1 = "bearer sDjdESddfEsdfdfwere2sEDaa2SmnsSkeew";
        //String input2 = null;

        
        // Scenario 3: -> Return Failed
        //String input1 = "bearer sDjdESddfEsdfdfwere2sEDaa2SmnsSkeew";
        //String input2 = "bearer ";

        // Scenario 4: -> Return Failed
        //String input1 = null;
        //String input2 = "bearer sDjdESddfEsdfdfwere2sEDaa2SmnsSkeew";

        
        
        String result = validate(input1, input2);
        System.out.println("result: " +result);

    }

    private static String validate(String input1, String input2) {
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Bearer (?<token>[a-zA-Z0-9-._~+/]+)=*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        String status ="failed";
        
        if (input1 != null && input2 != null) {
            
            if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input1, "bearer")
                    && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input2, "bearer")) {
                if (!pattern.matcher(input1).matches() || !pattern.matcher(input2).matches()) {
                    System.out.println("Pattern not match");
                    // throw  exception here
                }
                status = "success";
            }
        } else if (input1 != null) {
            if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input1, "bearer")) {
                if (!pattern.matcher(input1).matches()) {
                    System.out.println("Pattern not match");
                    // throw  exception here
                }
                status = "success";
            }

        }

        return status;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the ifs related to the same `input`

```
if (input1 != null) {
    if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input1, "bearer")) {

// INTO
if (input1 != null && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input1, "bearer")) {
```

And include the tests about `input2` inside the `if` for `input1`

---

#### Final code

```
private static String validate(String input1, String input2) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Bearer (?<token>[a-zA-Z0-9-._~+/]+)=*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String status = "failed";
    if (input1 != null && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input1, "bearer")) {
        if ((input2 != null && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(input2, "bearer") && !pattern.matcher(input2).matches())
                || !pattern.matcher(input1).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Pattern not match");
            // throw  exception here
        } else {
            status = "success";
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```